# Error when trying to get a specific user with expressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get an specific user in expressJs from a Json file

This is the error i'm getting.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

this is the code I'm using to get the specific user:

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  for (let i = 0; i < usersData.length; i++) {
    if (usersData[i].id == id) {
      console.log(usersData[i]);
      await res.send(usersData[i]);
    } else {
      res.json({ error: "Error" });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You cannot use `send()` or `json()` multlple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your loop logic needs to be revised to avoid multiple responses being sent to the client. With you current code, this will happen when mutliple items exist in the `usersData` array, seeing that `res.send()` or `res.json()` are called per iteration of `userData`.

One possiblity would be to revise your code as follows (the assumption being that you only want to return the first user, if any, that matches the request id):

```js
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  
  // Find user by id
  const user = usersData.find(data => data.id === id)
  
  // If user found, send to client or send error json
  if(user) {
    res.send(user);  
  }
  else {
    res.json({ error: "Error" });
  }
  
});
```